# How to disable Time log when running job in Rundeck?

Tags: bash, logging, rundeck

I tried to run some command lines in Rundeck, but it just logs the time every second, now the log is all over the place. How to disable this?

[image: log]

Below is my simple command line

[image: commandline]

Comment: It seems a script-related problem (curl / wget command I guess), you can make curl silent using the `-s` parameter, something like `curl -s http://myhost.net`. Same on wget with `-q` parameter: `wget -q myhost.net`.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k Thank it works. At first, I thought it was rundeck problem because when I ran the script locally, there was no log like this, only in rundeck. Turn out it's still the curl command problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a script-related problem (curl / wget command I guess), you can make curl silent using the `-s` parameter, something like `curl -s http://myhost.net`. Same on wget with the `-q` parameter: `wget -q myhost.net`.